# Preventing labels from covering symbols in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, labeling, point, symbology, cartography

In a single point dataset is it possible to get the labels to stop covering the symbols and be placed in a position that has white space automatically (i.e. without using data defined xy positions)?

[image]

**Should look like**

[image]
this is from the SVG, edited in Inkscape.

The settings for the labels are as follows. All the point data shown is in a single dataset.

[image]

[image]

I have tried Cartographic mode as well.

Should something change in the symbol properties?

[image]

I am using 3.22.0.

Answer (score 6):

For preventing label to get over your line layer just go to the labeling properties of your line layer (of course you could do that for any other layer you want to not be under label) then adjust your point layer label weight and the obstacle weight to get a result that suit you.

[image]

Comment: Yes thanks, I already have this as per my comment to sn1ks's answer. The issue here is preventing the labels from covering symbols in the same dataset.

Comment: I think your problem came from the point displacement renderer as the symbol are drawn in a different place than the real point position used by the labelling engine, you may try to increase the label distance factor (not sure of what this setting do but it's probably intended for this situation). You may also try to increase the label distance in the label setting

Comment: The problem with this solution, is that if the line layer (in this case) also has labels, then setting this drop down to 'Blocking' will turn its labels off.

Answer (score 3):

You should go to Layer properties -> Labels -> Placement
Set label priority to low, click on "Settings" under Obstacles and give them the highest weight possible. Maybe this helps!
[image]

Comment: Just tried but doesn't help. I want the labels to show, I just don't want them to cover labels in the same dataset. I assumed that Cartographic or Around Point with no Quadrant would move it to the most appropriate location. I also have a duplicate of the same dataset with Labels set as Obstacles but this didn't fix the issue.